# Is there a FAQ on "My questions was migrated, what next"

Tags: feature-request, migration, discussion

My question was migrated from SO, I linked my SO account to Meta-SO, but I can't edit or mark my question as answered. Is it [closed], and therefore should I just forget about it?

Comment: link to the question(s) please?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/low-views-and-no-answers-to-my-question-after-a-few-days-what-next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reply back from team@stackoverflow.com

> There is no current way to re-own a
>   question unless you had an account on
>   the target site prior to the question
>   migration.
>
> This is something we plan to get to in
>   the near future, however.
>
> The data in the database contains the
>   keys necessary to re-associate, so it
>   is possible to fix this after the
>   fact.

So the answer is probably forget about it in this case.

Comment: When did you get this response? According to the blog post a few days ago, they have the power to associate questions to an account, even if the account doesn't exist on the target site at the time of migration: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/

Comment: Today about an hour ago

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your accounts [remain unlinked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131563?tab=accounts#sort-top). Try linking them again.</strike>

You have different UserIDs ([131563](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131563) here on Meta, [133544](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133544/breadtruck) on SO). This means that you're two different people (to the system, you haven't developed schizophrenia that I'm aware of), and therefore, the closed question has a ghost user.

Methinks you have found a bug.

Comment: I did associate the accounts, so I tried again and my meta-SO shows linked to SO and vice-versa. So it must be somehting else.

Comment: Accounts will have different IDs. I'm 59303 here and on SO, but 289 on SU and 1071 on SF. All accounts have been correctly associated. I haven't had a question moved yet though.

Comment: Weird. I have the exact same ID on here as well as on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/users/95589/eric and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/95589/eric

Comment: I think the account numbers are the same between here and SO because Jeff did a mass copy of everyone's SO accounts. For the other sites you have to "sign up" and you'll do that in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to move your question to Meta, and you should have control over it (if not email team@stackoverflow.com). When an item gets migrated, it gets closed and locked on the original site, but it should be open and available for everyone on the place it was relocated to.

Comment: I sent the email. So our profiles, rep, badges etc are seperate between sites. Why?

Comment: @Bread: Rep and badges are separate because they are in different domains. Therefore, the level of trust I have at SO doesn't correspond to SF, and for good reason. I'm not trustworthy near servers. That's why I code.

Comment: When should I expect the question to be fixed and linked to my profile?