# Low views and no answers to my question after a few days, what next?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

I can imagine that after a few days my low viewed question with no answers is just going to be un-answered and un-viewed forever. I guess there isn't much interest in "Implementing a HierarchicalDataBoundControl". So what does someone do, delete and re-post? Are there tricks to getting your questions answered. It seems like everyone is quick to answer the easy ones, which is fine I guess, but with the kind of experts that use SO I would have expected at least one response or comment to two of my questions yet I have gotten nothing.

Update:
So my questions were as somebody put it "diarrhea of the mouth", fine I can accept the fact that they were not written very well. So when you edit and fix up your question, does it  move back up to the top or is it best to delete and repost a streamlined question?

Comment: But you earned the Tumbleweed Badge!

Comment: Add a link to your question and I'll look at it and tell you why I've ignored it.

Comment: I'll go edit it into shape, a bit.

Comment: You need to hire me for my SOO services - Stack Overflow Optimisation

Comment: What does belongs-on-meta mean?

Comment: It means that this question would be better suited for the meta.stackoverflow.com site.  (Of course, you would first have to know that it existed...something that isn't necessarily obvious.)

Comment: Try it now. I've edited a bit.

Comment: Looked at your other post. Same problem. It reminds me of when I was younger (much younger). I used to be accused of "diarrhea of the mouth".

Comment: I see what you mean, much better. At the time I think I wasn't allowed to have that many links, nor did I put them in correctly. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, that is what my wife says to me alot, I just ramble on and on ....... and on, get to the point

Comment: the answer is: edit, not duplicate, as your dupe will likely be closed as such.

Comment: That is all fine and dandy, but I can't edit it, because it no longer belongs to me after it got migrated

Comment: As a matter of fact why would you close my question knowing, from the other post that you replied in, that my question is no longer available to me for edit??

Comment: @Breadtruck: email team@stackoverflow.com and they can re-associate it with your account. it's probably Google OpenID weirdness that it hasn't already.

Comment: I already did email them, and I posted their reply and you commented on it in this other post, which is why I don't understand why you closed this one

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/is-there-a-faq-on-my-questions-was-migrated-what-next/6653#6653

Comment: OK, Breadtruck, because of the circumstances I've decided to do something unusual. I merged the original thread into the [Re-Visited] thread, and I replaced the content in the question with the original content. This way you can regain ownership of this post that was moved.

Comment: @Breadtruck: when you edit your question, it does come back up to the top in the default view. Personally, that's how I notice when someone has cleaned up a question, or added the information I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add as much detail as you can when you ask a question. There are too many one liner, no information, no code, no background, or too vauge questions sometimes.  These get downvoted or ignored because of this.

The other reason is maybe you actualy asked something that few people know about. People do not want to give you half answers or try and answer something they do not know about.

Answer (score 4):

If you want people to even view your question, you need to provide a title which **asks** a question. If SO users want to know the general topic of your question, they can just look at the tags which you **should** be tagging your questions with. Proper tagging is another effective way to get people viewing your questions.

From there, I have to agree with John Saunders and Trogy in that you need to get better at asking questions. Not to pick on you, but since you did ask, it's also a common courtesy to write your question using correct spelling and grammar, and to phrase what you're actually asking in as clear a way as possible. I'm not saying every SO user is a stickler for spelling and grammar, but it's just another thing that can turn people away prematurely.

Just in trying to understand your "UPDATE" to the above question, addressed to John Saunders, I had to read it multiple times through and then actually read John's comment (which prompted the update). Questions that are just plain hard to read and understand are more likely to result in people reading through a sentence or two and then moving on to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try raising your reputation so you can post a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, at least this way you can earn the Tumbleweed badge!

Comment: 4 more rep points and I can actually comment on another question without actually submitting an answer

Comment: Done.  You're in.  :-)

Comment: This is one badge I would rather not get.

Answer (score 0):

Reread it to see if you made it detailed enough. Do you have examples/would they help? I suppose you can edit the post and comment on it to bump it up. You can always add a bounty to it.

Also, remember that people browse with filtered views (by tag, by unanswered), so just because a few days go by doesn't mean it's invisible.

Answer (score 0):

More than detail, you need to get better at asking questions. This question doesn't really get started until it says, "When I moved on to the HierarchicalDataBoundControl I got stuck.". The rest is background that we may or may not need to know. I may not even have read through all that stuff.

Comment: SO just pose a question and forget the background, unless someone wants to know it?

Comment: No, say what you're trying to accomplish, but you don't need to go into the entire history of why you want to accomplish it, unless someone thinks it's relevant, like, "what made you think this was a good idea?"

Comment: I see your point