# Google login creating user named "Unknown (Google)"

Tags: support, google-openid

By and large, the Google OpenID login process has been going very smoothly for me recently, since discovering Stack Exchange and its various sites (I've been on Stack Overflow for a little while now -- and I don't recall the original login process, but it seems to have worked then, too?  Or maybe I merged things later, I don't recall).

However, on two sites recently, I've had problems.

First, I had the problem on meta.stackexchange.com, and I posted the question there, as soon as I did:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6633/google-openid-login-not-the-right-thing

In short, my account got created as an "unknown (Google)" user, instead of tied to my e-mail address, and automatically linked to my account on Stack Overflow, here, and on the various other sites I've logged in to.

All the other sites have worked fine for me, though, until yesterday, when I tried logging in to vfxoverflow.com, and had the same problem, but with simpler circumstances than I originally described.

This seems like a bug to me, since the behavior I did on vfxoverflow.com was, I'm quite certain, identical to what I'd done on other sites, and have done again since here on meta.stackoverflow.com (instead of meta.stackexchange.com, where I originally posted this question) -- and it's worked fine everywhere except meta.SE and vxfOF.  Certainly, it's a request for support, since I'm not sure how to fix it on meta.SE and vxfOF.  Tagging as both, since I'm not super familiar with this (meta.SO) site, and tagging policies (though I've read "[how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)").

I searched around for answers, with many of them seeming to have been asked before the [openid improvements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/), and others seeming to be about other issues (e.g. using a [Google Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps) account).

So, in summary, my questions are:

How come my attempts to login to meta.stackexchange.com and vfxoverflow.com have created an "unknown (Google)" account, instead of being associated with my e-mail address and other Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange accounts?

And/or:

What can I do to actually log in to those two sites in a way that will be associated with my other extant accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are Stack Exchange **1.0** sites -- they are based on an old fork of the code, and can't be linked with Stack Exchange 2.0 sites.

Information on the SE 1.0 to SE 2.0 transition:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Directory of SE 2.0 sites:
https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Ahh-hah.  OK, well, that explains it, I guess.  Thanks, Jeff.  I'm left unsure as to whether those sites will ever become SE 2.0 sites, though.  Will they?