# Is this question more suitable for AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was hesitating, since [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964363/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-application-integrated) is very ubuntu-centric, however it's about programming as well. It didn't seem to gain much attention. If I was right about putting it on SO, then how can I make it more attractive? It has a very low amount of views.

Comment: I can't speak to whether AU takes coding questions about Ubuntu, but I have a feeling it's going to get migrated to Programmers (and then closed) because you're asking for a list of resources. Instead, you ought to be asking "*How* do I integrate with X?" not "Can I get a list of resources for integrating with X?"

Comment: @Mark, if it's going to get migrated **and then closed**, then there's something going wrong. A question being migrated and then promptly closed is a waste of peoples time on TWO sites! :-/

Comment: @Rob [You are preaching to the choir.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: I know that "list" type questions (despite many of them existing) are not favorable, however, I don't know how I could ask it more specifically because I don't know that *'X'* is. And I think (or hope at least) that I can figure out the "how" part if I get to know the "what". Do you have a suggestion on how (or where) to ask a question like this?

Comment: And I also feel that despite being list-type, it is not a recommendation question, since there exists one definitive answer to it (namely the desktop-integration features of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as making a question more attractive:

[Low views and no answers to my question after a few days, what next?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/low-views-and-no-answers-to-my-question-after-a-few-days-what-next)

As far ask asking on AskUbuntu, I imagine that most of the users there would be more interested in your question whereas a much smaller portion of users on SO would have Ubuntu knowledge.  Yet this is a programming question, so Stack Overflow does make sense.  Adding a bounty might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your question is about programming AND about Ubuntu, but having just skimmed the first page of questions on askubuntu, there don't appear to be *any* questions that are programming orientated. That said, the "Welcome" box on the right does state:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for Ubuntu users and **developers**. It's 100% free, no registration required.

To clarify whether that means "people who develop Ubuntu" or "people who develop ON Ubuntu" you might want to ask a question on their meta.

As to how you can make your question more attractive:

- Break the block of text at the start apart; consider bullet points for the things you're after. It's easier for people to parse.
- Note any libraries/tools/frameworks/guidelines that you're already aware of; a starting point is useful to jog people
- When permitted offer a bounty; nothing draws people out of the woodwork like a bounty!

Bear in mind that you only asked your question 5 hours ago, I've given answers to questions (which were accepted!) days after it was posted, simply because I didn't see the question straight away!